# Bind function to Kivy button

Tags: python, function, button, bind, kivy

I'm trying to bind the following function to a `Button` in Kivy.

```
def auth(self):
    print(self.username)
    if self.username == "Hendricko":
        print("self.username == Hendricko")
        popup = Popup(title="success",
            content=Label(text="Howdy !"),
            size=(100, 100),
            size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
            auto_dismiss=False)
        popup.open()
```

I've tried

```
class Foo():
   def initUI(self):
    self.add_widget(Button(text="Auth User and Password", on_press=self.auth))
```

but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

here is my whole code

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.row = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)
        self.hello = Button(text="hello", on_press=self.auth)
        self.add_widget(self.hello)

    def auth(self):
        if self.username == "Hendricko":
            popup = Popup(title="success",
                content=Label(text="Howdy !"),
                size=(100, 100),
                size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                auto_dismiss=False)
            popup.open()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I'm guessing at your class structure, but it would be good if you could fill out the example of how you add your button and how you try to bind to it more completely - that's where the problem is, the `auth` function is only a detail here.

Comment: are you keeping auth in the same class Foo ? and are you using Widget or layout to show your data ?

Comment: yea sorry about the vague first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line

```
self.hello = Button(text="hello", on_press=lambda a:self.auth())
```

of your code and use this :

```
self.hello = Button(text="hello", on_press=lambda a:self.auth())
```

Also add below line in auth function to see if its called :)

```
print "auth called"
```

and There are many ways to perform a particular task .Above code will be to fix your code in minimum effort , However If you would like to do it in another way . Just use code below .

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.row = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)
        self.hello = Button(text="hello")
        self.hello.bind(on_press=self.auth)
        self.add_widget(self.hello)

    def auth(self,instance):
        print "auth called"
        if self.username == "Hendricko":
            popup = Popup(title="success",
                content=Label(text="Howdy !"),
                size=(100, 100),
                size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                auto_dismiss=False)
            popup.open()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks.appriciate it very much

Comment: @brousch  Answer is modified . Earlier way was to fix the code with minimum changes in his code .

Comment: Shouldn't you compare the value of the text input? Use if self.username.text == "Hendricko"

Comment: I don't see any difference between the first two lines

Answer (score 10):

I don't think any of the answers are very clear. Neither explains that problem is that the callback given to `on_press` gets called with a parameter, the instance of button, so `LoginScreen.auth` must accept a parameter after the `self`:

```
def auth(self, button):
    print('button pressed:', instance)
```

The problem is *not* that `on_press` must be given via `Button.bind` or that the callback must be a function, it can be a bound method, and the docs cited by other answer and by comments link to `ButtonbBhavior` which indicates that OP use of `on_press` in constructor was fine:

```
self.hello = Button(text="hello", on_press=self.auth)
```

would have worked if `auth` had been as described above.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [Button documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html), the key seems to be to use the `bind` function:

```
def callback(instance):
    print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)

btn1 = Button(text='Hello world 1')
btn1.bind(on_press=callback)
```

Comment: bind works well - I'm wondering is there a way to do this using the .kv language or does it have to be done within python?

Answer (score 0):

I report an example of buttons created dynamically within the main class, and then triggered into a single listener:

```
class allMyApp(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(allMyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #[...]

        for y in sorted(set(emissionYears)):
            btn = Button(text = y,
                         size_hint_y = None,
                         height = '48dp',
                         on_release = lambda btn: self.ids.choseEmissionDate.select(btn.text))
            btn.bind(on_press = self.sortByYear)
            self.ids.choseEmissionDate.add_widget(btn)

    def sortByYear(self, instance):
        year = instance.text
        print(year)
```