# How do you import another python file into Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I copied this piece of code from the internet to try to learn how Kivy works (btw it does work). I'm trying to import another python file I created called "Mifflin" (a calorie equation program) by using the command:

```
import Mifflin
```

with the rest of the imports. It imports it correctly but whenever I run the program it runs Mifflin and once its done executing the file it then runs the rest of the code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        # use a (r, g, b, a) tuple
        blue = (0, 0, 1.5, 2.5)
        red = (2.5, 0, 0, 1.5)
        btn =  Button(text='Touch me!', background_color=blue, font_size=120)        
        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.label = Label(text="------------", font_size='50sp')
        layout.add_widget(btn)
        layout.add_widget(self.label)
        return layout
    def callback(self, event):
        print("button touched")  # test
        self.label.text = "button touched"
TestApp().run()
```

My main goal is to press a button which then runs the program "Mifflin" and I don't know how to do that. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind function to Kivy button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127203/bind-function-to-kivy-button)

Comment: I can see how you think it's a duplicate but whats different is that I'm having trouble importing an external python file and then binding that to a button.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code looks similar to this:

```
import <that file>
print('hi')
```

and your console output will be:

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
button touched
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress... # Kivy app exits here
hi
```

because there's `TestApp().run()` at the end of the imported file. Do this to prevent it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

When `App.run()` method is called, Kivy starts its event loop, which in a very simple way looks like this:

```
while True:
    pass
```

and until such a loop is broken no code after it (therefore even after the import) will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So do you know if there is a way to include the imported file into the while loop?

Comment: @CodyOncken Yeah. Call it from the while loop. Or make some kind of listener inside the loop to check what's hapenning outside, e.g. with OSC(see kivy documentation).

Comment: How exactly would I call it from the While Loop though?

Comment: @CodyOncken You'd do the code directly in the file with `App.run()` method. It's not very useful doing it your way, rather doing it the other way around - file where is `App.run()` is the base and you import stuff into that. Or put at the end some IF like I mentioned, import something from the file, do some code and _then_ call `App.run()`… (all with the App instance, obviously).